# Is it possible to add Data source connection wizard in my app?

Tags: c#, .net, database, connection-string

Data source connection wizard is very convenient tool. Can I add it to my app to allow user choose data source themself in easy way?

Comment: I don't think you can but you could try to create your own wizard for choosing DB.

Comment: @Radu: I'm especially interested in creating user interface for easy building of connection strings. Have ever see an example of this for C#?

Comment: I am confused here. How will it benefit the user in case wrong database is selected. I think, your application is based on a particular database.

Comment: @SQL: Yes, you are partially right, but I'm developing a small tool for fixing data inconsistency in our (developed by my colleagues) DBs. This tool is used by system administrator, so the probability of choosing wrong DB is minimal

Comment: I think you should mention the database. SQL Server 2008/2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question on SO was answered with a shameless plug for a component they had developed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691669/data-connection-wizard-dialog

It's $50 but might save you some time...

**EDIT 1:** I am in no way linked to or involved in the product mentioned. I'm just passing on the information.

**EDIT 2:** 
Take a look at [A Visual SQL Query Designer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/QueryDesigner.aspx) project on CodeProject. You could extract the code for the connection dialog for your application as it is released under the [Code Project Open License](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for information! But I'm slightly confused about price... our project is not commercial so we not intend to spend money

Comment: That's fine, it's not my component. I just saw the answer and thought it might be of use to you. If you are time rich and cash poor than you I think you will have to develop your own wizard.

Comment: Great! Dialog from "A Visual SQL Query Designer" covers all my needs! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **User Control** to implement it.

System will pop Up a **ShowDialog Form**. This form will ask you following

1. UserName
2. Password
3. Server name
4. Database Name

Now use can connect to the database with your **Formatted Connection String** using the above mentioned parameters.

You can also make it generic by providing the Combobox. It will populate the database type like

1. **SQL Server** 2000/2005/2008
2. **MYSQL**
3. **MS Access**

The authenticated connection string can be used further utilized in the application. 
I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I found similar solution here - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DatabaseSpy_CS.aspx but main disadvantage of the solution there and in the solution you have provided - I have to manually implement server explorer and database selector. I hope, there is any solution without implementing server explorer and db selector

Comment: Yes, I think, you should do it manually for the long run. This will help you to customize your product anytime.

Comment: I'm going to wait up to two days if I dont get stright answer for my question. After that time I'll mark most convinient answer. For now your answer is most convinient

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this simply. cuz this form is in the `.net dll` and for using that you have two way:

1. one way is decompile .net dll (**this is illegal**)
2. do like `SQl` say

> Also there is simple to create something like that!

Answer (score 1):

Another option for OLEDB would be using the *Data Link Properties* Window.

```
private void dataLinkDialogButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ADODB.Connection conn = new ADODB.Connection( );
    object oConn = (object) conn;

    MSDASC.DataLinks dlg = new MSDASC.DataLinks( );
    dlg.PromptEdit(ref oConn);

    connectionStringTextBox.Text = conn.ConnectionString;
}
```

Look [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/adonet-cookbook/0596004397/ch01s14.html).